# How to keep a bootstrap4 tooltip open while hovering ON the tooltip itself?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

What I'm trying to accomplish is having a link that has a tooltip on hover.  Once the tooltip is shown, I'd like the tooltip to stay visible while the user hovers ON the tooltip itself.  I've looked over the bootstrap documentation, and I don't believe this functionality exists baked in.  I found some answers on how to do this with Bootstrap3, but I'm on Bootstrap4.

I did manage to sort of accomplish what I need using a delay on the tooltip.  It stays visible for 1 second after moving the mouse off of my link:

```
    $(function () {
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({delay: {show: 0, hide: 1000}});
    });
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/16gnysbp/

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can monkey patch Tooltip and prevent `hide()` if the mouse is positioned inside the tooltip itself. The tricky part is to keep track on the mouse and be sure that the tooltip is hidden when the mouse no longer hovers the tip. Here is a small demo:

```
var cx, cy, tip, waiting;
var old_hide = bootstrap.Tooltip.prototype.hide

var isOutside = function() {
  return ((cx < tip.left || cx > tip.left + tip.width) || 
          (cy < tip.top || cy > tip.top + tip.height))
}

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  cx = e.clientX
  cy = e.clientY
  if (waiting && isOutside()) {
    waiting.f.call(waiting.context)
    waiting = null
  } 
})

bootstrap.Tooltip.prototype.hide = function() {
  tip = this.getTipElement().getBoundingClientRect()
  if (isOutside()) {
    old_hide.call(this)
  } else {
    waiting = { f: old_hide, context: this }
  }
}
```

forked fiddle -> **https://jsfiddle.net/8v2ds7Lt/**

It also works with multiple tooltips. The code should be wrapped into something more elegant, just demonstrating the concept.

Comment: This does exactly what I need.  Javascript isn't a language that I use very often, so I appreciate the working example.  Thanks again!

Comment: what resource is required to access `bootstrap.Tooltip.prototype.hide`?

Comment: Working fine. Added this after tooltip initialization.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a [Popover](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/popovers/) would be a better way to achieve your goal.

In my example I have wrapped the button in a span and on hover of the span the button becomes focused. Them to prevent the popover disappearing add the `data-triger="focus"` to the button.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zfagk81m/6/)

EDIT:
I see that you actually want to be able to copy the text, this was working for me but when i reloaded it stopped... strange.
[This is probably not the way you are meant to do this](https://jsfiddle.net/zfagk81m/7/), however i have set the `data-trigger` attribute to manual so that you can control the `show` and `hide` completely. A button will appear when the popover is shown so the user can close it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the selected answer, but using ES6 class inheritance so variables gets encapsulated on each tooltip object instead of using global variables. I also added a `errorMargin` constant so it's more permissive on mouse position and prevent the tooltip to close if mouse movement is not precise.

```
import Tooltip from "bootstrap/js/src/tooltip";

let cx, cy = 0;

class HoverableTooltip extends Tooltip {
  constructor(element, config) {
    super(element, config);
    this.waiting = false;
  }

  isOutside() {
    const errorMargin = 10;
    const { left, width, top, height } =
      this.getTipElement().getBoundingClientRect();
    return (
      cx < left - errorMargin ||
      cx > left + width + errorMargin ||
      cy < top - errorMargin ||
      cy > top + height + errorMargin
    );
  }

  forceHide() {
    super.hide();
  }

  hide() {
    if (this.isOutside()) {
      super.hide();
    } else {
      this.waiting = true;
    }
  }
}

const tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(
  document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]')
);
const tooltips = tooltipTriggerList.map((tooltipTriggerEl) => {
  return new HoverableTooltip(tooltipTriggerEl);
});
document.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
  cx = e.clientX;
  cy = e.clientY;
  tooltips.forEach((tooltip) => {
    if (tooltip.waiting && tooltip.isOutside()) {
      tooltip.forceHide();
      tooltip.waiting = false;
    }
  });
});
```